# CRS for Lat/Long points and QuickMapServices

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, csv, quickmapservices

I have data from Google maps with latitudes and longitude recorded like this:

| lat | long | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35.05 | 135.76 | Kyoto |
| 44.24 | -123.72 | Corvallis |

The coordinates are from Google maps. The only CRS which displays all of the points is WGS 84 EPSG: 3857; other CRS display the points in wrong locations, only the first point, or no point at all. When I use the EPSG: 3857, however, no QuickMapServices maps work. The most they will display is a blue background.

Answer (score 1):

Use WGS 84 (EPSG::4326) to to define the coordinates (CRS) of the data and load `OpenStreetMAP (OSM)` data from `QuickMapServices (QMS)` normally, and the data will be located in the correct location after **zooming in** to the point location.

Here is an output of the data:

- (Kyoto)

[image]

- (Corvallis)

[image]